# Using Google AdWords keyword planner

Tags: seo

when using `Google AdWords keyword planner` to get search volume etc. for a search term, I sometimes get back this message from the tool:

> We can't display search volume charts because your keywords don't have
>   any searches.

Obviously this pops up on low search volume terms, but still, it strikes me as odd - was this term NEVER EVER searched for (in selected date range)?

I am interested in low volume terms, but for some of the terms returning this message it just doesn't make sense. Is there a search volume threshold under which the tool won't present data? maybe statistics are calculated only if a term surpasses the threshold?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: why SEO topics are off-topic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that they do still go monthly: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3022575?hl=en&ref_topic=3175091

This might also interest you, 2rn: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2616014?hl=en